# Incrementing sequence number on SQL insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert, sequence

Is there a simple way to insert multiple rows and increment a particular field, using SQL Server 2005?

Note, I am **not** looking for a solution involving an `identity` column - see the bottom of the question for an explanation

(The following schema and data have been replicated [here in this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a5a4/3/0).)

For instance, consider the following table and data...

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE (
   [PKID] INT IDENTITY, [FKID] INT, [MYTEXT] VARCHAR(10), [SEQUENCE] INT
)
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE ([FKID], [MYTEXT], [SEQUENCE]) VALUES (1, 'one', 1)
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE ([FKID], [MYTEXT], [SEQUENCE]) VALUES (1, 'two', 2)

-- Table data
PKID  FKID  MYTEXT  SEQUENCE
1     1     one     1
2     1     two     2
```

And the following data to be inserted...

```
DECLARE @FKID INT
SET @FKID = 1
DECLARE @NEWDATA XML
SET @NEWDATA = '<data><text>three</text><text>four</text></data>'
```

**Can the following be written in such as way that the `SEQUENCE` field comes out as `1,2,3,4` instead of the `1,2,3,3` that is currently does?**

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE ([FKID], [MYTEXT], [SEQUENCE])
SELECT @FKID, 
       X.value('.','VARCHAR(10)'),
       (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([SEQUENCE]),0)+1 FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE [FKID]=@FKID)
FROM @NEWDATA.nodes('/data/text') AS X(X)

-- Actual result...
PKID  FKID  MYTEXT  SEQUENCE
1     1     one     1
2     1     two     2
3     1     three   3
4     1     four    3  <-- Issue

-- Required result...
PKID  FKID  MYTEXT  SEQUENCE
1     1     one     1
2     1     two     2
3     1     three   3
4     1     four    4
```

---

Update:

In response to the comment by @marc_s...

> Identity would be the best solution for 2005... best solution by far - why do you explicitly exclude it and insist on rolling your own? (with all the risks of causing duplicates and so on....)

The table in question will hold multiple sets of `SEQUENCE` values, each "set" based on the `FKID` value... therefore the table could hold data along these lines...

```
PKID  FKID  MYTEXT  SEQUENCE
1     1     one     1
2     1     two     2
3     1     three   3
4     1     four    4
5     2     ett     1
6     2     tva     2
7     2     tre     3
```

Comment: I believe any easy way to do this requires SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Yes, @Pieter, I'm sure it would be easier - unfortunately I'm stuck with 2005, as that is our minimum supported DB and a lot of our clients are still using it

Comment: Because, @marc_s, the sequence is directly related to the foreign key column.  I.e. `FKID=1` can have multiple rows with `SEQUENCE=1,2,3` and `FKID=2` can also have `SEQUENCE=1,2`.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear in the OP

Comment: any reason you can't use a variable to do it? Declare it, and increment to it from your select statement? Write the variable at the end.

Comment: Sorry @Random, I don't fully understand **how** you'd use a variable... please feel free to provide an answer with your solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test on 2005, but you should be able to use a CTE just fine to number things;

```
DECLARE @FKID INT
SET @FKID = 1
DECLARE @NEWDATA XML
SET @NEWDATA = '<data><text>three</text><text>four</text><text>five</text></data>'

;WITH cte AS (SELECT @FKID FKID, X.value('.','VARCHAR(10)') a, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X) r
             FROM @NEWDATA.nodes('/data/text') AS X(X))
INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE ([FKID], [MYTEXT], [SEQUENCE])
SELECT fkid, a,
  (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([SEQUENCE]),0)+r FROM TEMPTABLE WHERE [FKID]=cte.fkid)
FROM cte;

SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE;
```

which gives the result:

```
1    1    one     1
2    1    two     2
3    1    three   3
4    1    four    4
5    1    five    5
```

---

**UPDATE**

If the query will ever insert only one FKID, the following simplified version would work as well (the necessary changes to your current query are highlighted):

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE ([FKID], [MYTEXT], [SEQUENCE])
SELECT @FKID, 
       X.value('.','VARCHAR(10)'),
       (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([SEQUENCE]),0)+1 FROM #TEMPTABLE WHERE [FKID]=@FKID)
        + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM @NEWDATA.nodes('/data/text') AS X(X)
```

The purpose of `(SELECT 1)` in the `ROW_NUMBER`'s `ORDER BY` clause is to avoid specifying any particular order. It can be changed to something else (e.g. to `X.value('.','VARCHAR(10)'`), if necessary.

Comment: +1, although a CTE is unnecessary. Just removing the `+1` from the subquery and adding `+ROW_NUMBER() ...` after the subquery would be enough, i.e. the expression for the `SEQUENCE` column would look like this: `(SELECT ISNULL(MAX([SEQUENCE]),0) FROM TEMPTABLE WHERE [FKID]=cte.fkid) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))`.

Comment: Thank you, Joachim, for your answer, you were definitely in the right direction.  But @AndriyM, you have hit the nail on the head, and that is exactly what I needed (although the `[FKID]=ctr.fkid` should be `[FKID]=@FKID`). If you make that an answer, I will happily mark it.

Comment: @freefaller: I would have posted my answer if it was really different from this one, [which works fine for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11345) by the way. The only issue with this answer I can see is that, while testing, Joachim added one more item, `five`, to the `@NEWDATA` XML but forgot to reflect that in the posted output. I would also argue that in this particular solution, which uses a CTE, both `[FKID]=cte.fkid` and `[FKID]=@FKID` work perfectly well. In time, however, you might want to modify the CTE to generate rows for multiple FKIDs, and `[FKID]=cte.fkid` would work better.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying @AndriyM - but the query will only ever deal with a single FKID at one time, so simply having the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` does exactly what I need, without the use of the CTE.  If you're happy for Joachim to get the mark, then I'm fine with that as well. Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
    INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE ([FKID], [MYTEXT], [SEQUENCE])
    SELECT @FKID, 
               X.value('.','VARCHAR(10)'),
              (SELECT ISNULL(Count(*),0)+1 FROM #TEMPTABLE)
    FROM @NEWDATA.nodes('/data/text') AS X(X)
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles, but same result, the initial count is used on both insert rows... so you still get `3` appearing twice.  Also, this wouldn't take into account the (unlikely, but still possible) situation where the `SEQUENCE` isn't contiguous from `1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with data as (
  select * from ( values
    (1,1,'one'),
    (2,1,'two'),
    (3,1,'three'),
    (5,1,'five'),
    (6,1,'six')
  ) data(PKID, FKID, MYTEXT)
) 
select lhs.*, sequence = count(*)
from data lhs
left join data rhs on rhs.FKID = lhs.FKID 
  and rhs.PKID <= lhs.PKID
group by 
  lhs.PKID,
  lhs.FKID,
  lhs.MYTEXT
```

yielding this:

```
PKID        FKID        MYTEXT sequence
----------- ----------- ------ -----------
1           1           one    1
2           1           two    2
3           1           three  3
5           1           five   4
6           1           six    5
```

Comment: Sorry, @Pieter, I'm having trouble seeing how I can integrate your answer with my insert statement and XML data

Comment: (1) The `with` block simply supplies some test data for verification. (2) The remaining `select` statement is intended to replace the `select` clause in your `insert` statement.